# R caret with reproducible outcome/results

Tags: r, r-caret, random-seed

I am using the `caret` package in `R` for some supervised multivariate analysis. I am trying to add some functionality to my script that will allow for reproducible outcomes whenever the script is run.

I have this setup for using 2 classification models (each model is run separately, not as an enesmble):

```
library(caret)

load.data = ....
cleaned.data = cleaning(load.data)
mycontrol = trainControl(...)
train, test = createDatapartition(...)

model1 = train(...,
               data=train, ...,
               trControl=mycontrol,
               preprocess=c('center'))
model2 = train(...,
               data=train, ...,
               trControl=mycontrol,
               preprocess=c('pca'))

feature.importances = ...
summary(resamples(list(m1=model1,m2=model2)))
learing_curve_dat(...) #see link 1. below.
predict()
Evaluate(....) #see link 2. below
```

Where in this pipeline should I use [`set.seed(#)`](http://rfunction.com/archives/62) and what should [`#`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13605506/4057186) be in order to get reproducible outcomes each time the script is run - or do I just pick any value for `#` randomly?

Links:

[1.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-76/topics/learing_curve_dat)
[2.](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/03/com_class_eval_metrics_r.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [Notes on Reproducibility](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#notes-on-reproducibility) section on the package web page.

The seed number doesn't matter. I generate one with `sample.int(100000, 1)`. Depending on how you are doing the model, you at least should set the seed just prior to calling `train` (but please read the link above).