# Horizontal lines from 0 to point in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

Is it possible to add horizontal lines from 0 to the points on the plot shown below?

This is the code thus far:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=change, y=industry, color=geo)) + geom_point() + 
scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + geom_vline(xintercept = 0)
```

Alternatively, I could use `geom_bar()` but I have been unsure how to show both London and the UK without them summing together.

[image: image link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** you can use `geom_bar()` with `position="stack", stat="identity"`. Or you can use `geom_segment()`.

### set up data

```
dd <- expand.grid(industry=c("property",
                            "manufacturing",
                            "other"),
                 geo=c("London","UK"))
set.seed(101)
dd$change <- runif(6,min=-30,max=30)
```

This is how you could do it with `geom_bar`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd,aes(x=industry,y=change,
              fill=geo))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
           position="dodge")+
  coord_flip()
```

Or with `geom_segment()`:

```
ggplot(dd,aes(x=change,y=industry,
              colour=geo))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  geom_segment(aes(xend=0,yend=industry))
```

You might want to consider manually dodging the position in the second case, but `position_dodge` in `ggplot` can only dodge horizontally, so you should either switch x and y and use `coord_flip()`, or use `position_dodgev` from the `ggstance` package.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try! Would you be able to explain the purpose of the `set.seed()` function when setting up the data? I understand it is for random number generation but further than that I'm unclear

Comment: have you looked around on the web? There's probably even a good explanation on SO somewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605271/reasons-for-using-the-set-seed-function