# Basic loop index in a function

Tags: r, loops

I want to add a loop to the code below so that it runs four times for

```
n <- c(1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000)
```

And to return a matrix that contains `n` values and its solution `pi`? Thanks!

Here is my code for a single value of `n`:

```
n <- 1000
x <- c(runif(n, -1,1))
y <-c(runif(n, -1,1))
points <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))

z <- points$x^2 + points$y^2
pi <- function(n,points){
  y <- 4*length(z[z<=1])/n
  return(y)
}
pi(n, points)
```

Comment: just add `for (n in c(1000,  10000, 100000, 1000000)) {`
and close the curly bracket at the end.

Comment: @Cettt thanks but it only shows the last run as output, and I'd like to see a matrix(4x2), 2 columns n and pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a way where you use an implicit loop (`sapply`) instead of a for loop:

```
calc_pi <- function(n){
  x <- c(runif(n, -1,1))
  y <-c(runif(n, -1,1))
  points <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))

  z <- points$x^2 + points$y^2
  pi <- function(n,points){
    y <- 4*length(z[z<=1])/n
    return(y)
  }
  pi(n, points)
}

n <- c(1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000)
set.seed(1)
data.frame(n = n, pi = sapply(n, calc_pi))
      n       pi
1 1e+03 3.080000
2 1e+04 3.141600
3 1e+05 3.137640
4 1e+06 3.143064
```

Note that it is good practice to set a random seed with `set.seed` when working with random numbers (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605271/reasons-for-using-the-set-seed-function)).

Comment: Thanks. If I use set, I would lose the randomness of the output everytime I run the code, or in other words, with set.seed I get the same answer each time I run the code

Comment: exactly. But this makes your results reproducible