# Converting values to NA with conditions in R

Tags: r, missing-data, naniar

I'm trying to convert variables to NA(missing) with conditions

This is my data as example. I have 5 patients ID, If there is '1' in `missing` variable, `outcome1` and `outcome2` will be converted to NA(missing).

```
  ID<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
  cond1<-as.factor(sample(x=1:7,size=5,replace=TRUE))
  cond2<-as.factor(sample(x=1:7,size=5,replace=TRUE))
  cond3<-as.factor(sample(x=1:7,size=5,replace=TRUE))
  missing<-as.factor(sample(x=0:1,size=5,replace=TRUE))
  outcome1<-sample(x=1:10, size=5,replace=TRUE)
  outcome2<-sample(x=1:10, size=5,replace=TRUE)
  df<-data.frame(ID,cond1,cond2,cond3,missing,outcome1,outcome2)
  df
   ID cond1 cond2 cond3 missing outcome1 outcome2
1  a     7     1     7       0       6       5
2  b     5     3     7       0       3       1
3  c     4     5     1       1       3       9
4  d     2     2     3       0       7       3
5  e     1     7     4       1       2       7
```

I've found the `replace_with_na_at` function, in `naniar` package. however, it didn't worked.

```
df%>%
  replace_with_na_at(.vars=c("outcome1","outcome2"), condition = ~ hn10_14med$missing==1)

Error: Predicate functions must return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not a logical vector of length 0
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

How to convert variable to NA with conditions? If there is a better way, though not using `replace_with_na_at` function, you would let me know.

Comment: In your sample data there are no columns `outcome1` and `outcome2`. Can you show the expected output? Don't forget to [set a seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605271/reasons-for-using-the-set-seed-function) for reproducibility.

Comment: Oh, I made serious mistake. I corrected it. Thanks for your noticing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the values in place, just use ifelse:

```
df[df$missing==1,c("cond1", "cond2")] <- NA
```

Comment: The replacement is right. I corrected my mistake. Thanks for your help.