# how to find expected value of 1000 random number of Poisson Distribution

Tags: r, statistics

Generate a vector of 1000 Poisson random numbers with λ = 3. Make a histogram and a boxplot of the 1000 numbers. Find the expected value of the vector in Rstudio

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just for information, SO is not meant to make your homework for you. Instead, we can  answer specific programming-related questions.

Comment: thank you sir for your comment. but first of all, this is not my homework. Randomly I am working on R programming and I have a problem finding expected value. Now I know that why we use set.seed() because I am new in R programming. So I was just getting help from others. that's it. Again this is not my homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
set.seed(123)
#Code
v <- rpois(1000,lambda = 3)
#Hist
hist(v)
#Boxplot
boxplot(v)
#Mean
mean(v)
```

Comment: Sir why we use [set.seed(123)]  and how to find the expected value. Kindly can you guide me further

Comment: Setting a seed is done in order to reproduce the same results. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605271/reasons-for-using-the-set-seed-function

Comment: What are you calling an expected value?