# I don't understand why set_seed is needed with torch and tensorflow import

Tags: python, numpy, torch, bert-language-model

```
def set_seed(seed: int):
    """
    Helper function for reproducible behavior to set the seed in ``random``, ``numpy``, ``torch`` and/or ``tf`` (if
    installed).

    Args:
        seed (:obj:`int`): The seed to set.
    """
    random.seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    if is_torch_available():
        torch.manual_seed(seed)
        torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
        # ^^ safe to call this function even if cuda is not available
    if is_tf_available():
        import tensorflow as tf

        tf.random.set_seed(seed)

set_seed(1)
```

This code is executed at the beginning of the bert fine-tuning code. Can you please help me to understand the purpose of this code?

Comment: It stops things from being random if they all start from a consistent point

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of this is to ensure that results are reproducible, i.e. that you will get the same outcome every time.

For more detail see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13605506/12545041) answer to the same question asked about the R `set.seed()` function.